# Aspect function creating empty raster using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, aspect

I am trying to derive the aspect from an elevation file. When I run the function it creates a new file but the file is empty. my code:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.overwriteOutput = True

elevation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

outRaster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)


env.workspace = os.path.dirname(elevation)

inputElev = os.path.basename(elevation)

saveReclass = arcpy.env.workspace + os.sep + outRaster

northRangeone = 22.5
northRangetwo = 337.5

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

inRaster = elevation
out_aspect = Aspect(inputElev)
out_aspect.save(arcpy.env.workspace + os.sep + inputElev + "Aspect")
```

Comment: Try changing `inputElev = os.path.basename(elevation)` to `inputElev = Raster(elevation)`

Comment: For your various uses of `os.path.basename()` - I'm not sure why you'd be using unqualified file names (basenames) instead of fully qualified paths.

Comment: You should also make it more clear what you mean by "a blank file".  Do you mean a file that is zero bytes in size on disk (ie, an empty file), or a file that is a raster that is all one value (eg, appears all white, or all the same colour)?  Or something else?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please do not delete and re-ask questions.  We need you to edit the original question if you have clarifications to provide or new information to add.  Please check out our short [Tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.